# iOS UIStepper on Android

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, android-widget

I'm working for the first time on Android. I'm making an app where, at some point, the user has the possibility to set a quantity for a product.

I'm wondering if, on android, is there something like the iOS UIStepper or a way in order to add a DatePicker with only the Year field.

Comment: Because i'm talking about the UIStepper too. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a way in order to add a DatePicker with only the Year field

`NumberPicker` was added with API Level 11. If you are trying to support older Android devices than that, you can try to create your own `NumberPicker` based on [the original's source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java).

Comment: Great! This is what i was looking for. I'm working for API 11 (from 11 to ICS) and this is good for me. One thing, i can't make this picker work well. In the emulator i there is no + or - button so i cannot increase or decrease the value :( What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

DatePicker cannot be used for Year alone.
You have to create a custom dialog or a spinner to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html). ps. [have a look at here too](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)

Comment: Yet saw that. But, no. I'm not looking for a spinner because the spinner is for display a list of something. I need something to let the user increase or decrease a quantity (from 0 to infinite) . The DataPicker with only the year field only was an idea, the spinner is a little too "list-oriented".

Comment: If we only knew purpose of this :(